# collapse panel - how to open one but close others

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery code that adds a class of 'close' and slides in an element, but I want all others to close when one of them is opened. So if I click to open one of them, I want the others that are open to close, but I can't do it.
HTML:

```
<div class="main">
<h2>Question 1?</h2>
  <div class="answer">
    <p>bla bla bla</p>
  </div>
  <h2>question 2</h2>
  <div class="answer">
    <p>bla bla bla</p>
  </div>
  <h2>Question 3?</h2>
  <div class="answer">
    <p>bla bla bla</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have this jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.answer').hide();
 $('.main h2').toggle(
    function() {
       $(this).next('.answer').slideDown();
       $(this).addClass('close');

    },
    function() {
       $(this).next('.answer').fadeOut();
       $(this).removeClass('close');
  }
    ); // end toggle
}); // end ready
</script>
```

i tried adding this to the first function but on click it just slides down and then up.

```
$('.main .answer').not(this).slideUp();
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you are purposely trying to roll your own solution here, but you are attempting to create an **Accordion Panel** control.  Since you're using jQuery, you can also take advantage of the jQueryUI library's version of this control, which is fully featured and very customizable: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.answer').hide();
    $('.cat_info h2').on('click', function() {
        var state = $(this).next('.answer').is('.open');
        if (state) {
            $(this).next('.answer').removeClass('open').fadeOut();
        }else{
            $(this).next('.answer').addClass('open').slideDown()
                   .siblings('.answer').removeClass('open').slideUp();
        }
    });
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/kahZw/1/)

FYI: `toggle()` used that way is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/)

Comment: it wont open anything. its not sliding down

Comment: ACtually I copied the html and js from fiddle and it works! Thanks! IOne more thing, how would I add a certain class to h2 when it's opened?

Comment: @user1091508 - You would add a class to the `H2` element the same way as above, but use `addClass` and `removeClass` directly on `$(this)`, and not on the next `.answer` etc. If the answer works you should also accept it.

Comment: I can't do it on my own. I will accept the answer as soon as it is complete. Without adding and removing a class to h2 it is half job done. I do appreciate your time but this is half the answer.

Comment: I added addclass and removeclass but that just adds the class to each one and it stays with each one: $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.answer').hide();
    $('.cat_info h2').on('click', function() {
        var state = $(this).next('.answer').is('.open');
        if (state) {

            $(this).removeClass('open').next('.answer').removeClass('open').fadeOut();

        }else{

            $(this).addClass('open').next('.answer').addClass('open').slideDown().siblings('.answer').removeClass('open').slideUp();
        }
    });
});

Comment: I guess something like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/kahZw/3/) then? <- Ooops, updated the fiddle.

Comment: But when I have these divs inside other divs it doesn't work. For example if I had h2 and answer div both inside a div, then it wont work. Why?

Comment: Because it targets the siblings, i.e. the elements in the same "scope" as the clicked element etc. If you change the markup, you need to also change the javascript to reflect the new markup.